# How to use jQuery Ajax autocomplete in ASP.NET Core MVC with ADO.NET

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

Script added for autocomplete:

```
$("txtSearch").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/ProductSearchDisplay/GetProductDetailsById/',
                            data: "{'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                                debugger
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    return item;
                                }))
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            },
                            failure: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function (e, i) {
                        $("#txtSearch").val(i.item.val);
                    },
                    minLength: 1
                });
            })
```

Method in the controller which send data in list:

```
public JsonResult GetProductDetailsById(String prefix)
{
    List<ProductMaster> ObjProduct = new List<ProductMaster>();
    ObjProduct = objProductData.SearchProductData(prefix).ToList();
    ViewBag.data = ObjProduct;            
    return Json(ObjProduct);
}
```

The code is not working for autocomplete search added script as well.

Comment: "Not working" is very broad. Did you debug, and looked if the error was in your C# or js code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The returning JSON must be an Array list or an Array of Objects with `{label, value}` pairs at a minimum. Please provide an example of the return data or a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: check the response data from your backend controller, I mean the data in  `success: function (data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the issue is missing "#"

[image]

and this is my test code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="txtSearch" />
<script>
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
    //source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript"],
    source: function (request, response) {
        var param = { "prefix": request.term};
        $.ajax({
            url: '/test/getData/',
            //data: "{'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
            data: JSON.stringify(param),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return item;
                }))
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (e, i) {
        $("#txtSearch").val(i.item.val);
    },
    minLength: 1
});
</script>
```

And this is my controller, I didn't complete the filter:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getData([FromBody] TestModel model)
{
    List<string> res = new List<string>
    {
        "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript"
    };
    return Json(res);
}
```

Comment: even with this when search its not showing list but blank list display

Comment: try to use `//source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript"],` first to make sure the autocomplete method worked well.

Comment: then you may check if your backend api returned correct data, I guess the `blank list` comes from the backend, maybe the 'prefix' doesn't passed to the backend

Comment: @sonaliborekarr using `var param = { "prefix": request.term};` to be the data and set the data as `data: JSON.stringify(param),` in ajax request. I modified my answer just now and pls update your question by click the `edit` button behind your question, but not put your update as an answer.